# Checking if a cell is not empty on javascript

Tags: javascript

What i'm trying to do is to verify if a cell is not empty, in which case, the cells to the right shouldn't be empty either. Clearly the problem I encounter is with the not null verification in the array. I've tried using if (values[y].isEmpty; values[y]!==""; values[y]!==null but all the previous options fail. The problem is with the condition not being met whether the cell is empty or not.

```
function validate()
    {
        var range = hojaR13A.getRange("E7:E15");
        var values = range.getValues();
        var i = [];
        for (var y = 0; y < values.length; y++)
        {
            if(values[y]!=="")
            {
                i.push(y);
            }
        }
        var valRow = Number(i)+Number(range.getRow());
```

I've used the exact same code before with conditions of equal to, rather than not equal to, and it has always worked. What am I missing? Thanks in advance

Comment: `console.log(values[y]);` <= what values are failing that you expect to pass?

Comment: Also if you push multiple numbers to an array (which `i` is), `Number(i)` will result in NaN

Comment: please show the values of you array. you might have to take caree of empty spaces as well

Comment: What are cells? Is this excel? Maybe put an excel tag as well if so?

Comment: I'm working on google sheets, and every value was failing to pass, whether it was an empty cell or not. The answer Eugen Sunic gave worked for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to push values which exist. Also you should check wether the cell has empty spaces, if yes it should **not** be added to the array.

```
if (values[y] && values[y].toString().trim()) {
   i.push(y)
}
```